# AWS + multiple IP + get requests to an API

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, bots

I would like to write a trading bot for my local stock exchange, however its API only allows 1 requests per second per IP which provides a lot less information than I require. I am wondering how can I use AWS to override that problem.

How can I use for example 10 different instances with different IP's that would return information from the public API and use it in my main instance in real-time for the analysis in python and then sending post requests to the exchange? Instead of using several instances, can it be done by using only one instance with several elastic ip's and switching IP after every request? Is it possible to do this task with AWS Batch?

I would categorize myself as a novice programmer, I would be grateful if you can me push me into the correct direction.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that the "correct direction" is not to ask for help violating the API provider's terms of use by disguising the origin of your traffic.  If they would not object to you using 10 IPs to make 10x the number of requests, then they should also not object to providing you with a mechanism that would allow you to make 10x the requests from a single IP.  If they do, then this is sending a message to you that gaming their system is not the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for the information.